# Pandas assign value if value from one dataframe exists in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have 2 dataframes. 
One has list of locations (countries and cities), and another one has locations with corresponding info (e.g. coordinates).

First one, our_data:
[our_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGVES.jpg)

Second one, db:
[db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcv0U.jpg)

What I want to is, I want to check if *countries* in *our_data* exist in *common* in *db*. The thing is, *countries* is scraped from Twitter, and it is messy, so basically I want to check if any of the words in the string correspond to *common* dataset in another dataframe. Also, if there is a match, I want to save te *latlng* from *db* as another column in *our_data*.

So far, I tried iterating through columns somehow, mostly unsuccessful (this is my first time working with Pandas, and I am doing a Twitter scraper and want to to map for each tweet). The closes I got was with this:

```
our_data = our_data.assign(test = our_data.countries.isin(db.common))
```

and get this result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fE1x.jpg)

I tried with

```
our_data = our_data.assign(test = db.latlng if (our_data.countries.isin(db.common)) else "False")
```

and got this Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a left join to do that:

```
import pandas as pd

result = pd.merge(our_data, db, how="left", left_on="countries", right_on="common")
```

You will get a dataframe with 5 columns: countries, primary_location, common, latlng capital1. Columns common, latlng and capitla1 contain NaN values if no matches were found.

Comment: Thank you! The thing is, with this I get _common, latlng and capitla1_ if there is exact match (e.g., countries is the same as capital). If, for example, I have "London England" in _countries_, it does not find a match with "England" in _common_, and I would love if to do that. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: The dataframe I get looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/C5FkZU1t)

Comment: @Gabriela how can I help you if you don't tell me the format of the countries column? I thought it contains country names and now it turns out that it may contains country name + capital.... Be more clear, update your question with an example (input and expected output) and then I will help you